# boostrap nav don't work angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to migrate my site with AngularJS but I have an issue with menu.
Usually my menu is like

[image: this]

but when I put my menu in index.html (I include the same files), my menu is like

[image: this]...

Index.html:

```
<!-- Navigation panel -->
<nav class = "main-nav js-stick">
  <div class = "full-wrapper relative clearfix">
    <div class = "nav-logo-wrap local-scroll">
        <img src = "" alt = "" />
    </div>
    <div class = "mobile-nav">
      <i class = "fa fa-bars"></i>
    </div>

    <!-- Main Menu -->
    <div class="container">
    <div class="inner-nav desktop-nav">
      <ul class="clearlist">
        <li><a href="#" class="mn-has-sub">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="mn-has-sub">Calc<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
          <ul class="mn-sub to-left">
            <li><a href="#">toto</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">titi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">tata</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- End Navigation panel -->

<div ng-view>
</div>
```

And when my mouse is on Calc, nothing happening. :/

Thx,

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Something is clearly different between the two and angular doesn't care what css is used or modify style unless you tell it to

Comment: I'd rather he first provide a question